# ASP.Net Connection string woes

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string, asp.net-3.5, hosted

My **hosted** ASP.NET 3.0 Forms application is suddenly throwing `Login failed for user 'SQL2008R2_llama_user'.`

This means that the database credentials are wrong. I find out my DB Manager changed the DB password, and that the new password is `!@#$%^&*llama123456` . So I plug in the new password into my configuration files.

**Problem:** My application still can't connect and throws the same error.

Connection String:

```
Data Source=tcp:sql2k804.discountasp.net; Initial Catalog=SQL2008R2_llamadatabase;
uid=SQL2008R2_llama_user; pwd=!@#$%^&*llama123456;Connect Timeout=300;
```

Troubleshooting Steps:

- I **can** log into MSSQL SMS using `tcp:sql2k...` and using `sql2k ...` with the credentials. This means the credentials are correct.
- The problem persists on a different webhost and domain
- The app recompiles succesfully each config file edit
- I double-checked the config file changes and they are being edited accordingly

What else can I try? Is my hosted database throwing a temper-tantrum because of the special characters in my password? Any ideas?

Comment: Obligatory note that the credentials are not real, but similar, and not similar enough to guess at.

Comment: have you tried to use SqlConnectionStringBuilder to build your connection string? I am guessing if something needs to be escaped, it will handle it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own problem.

I had forgotten that I had connection strings in my Web.config and Global.asax.

When in doubt, CTRL-F your solution!